# Regex101 to Grep/egrep returns nothing

Tags: bash, sed, grep, regular-expression, pcre

I've been playing with the following regex to cut some content from a markdown file for me which works great in regex101 but can't seem to get grep to work with it.

Either it errors or doesn't return anything

The Regex is here: https://regex101.com/r/XDImM9/1
or `(?s)##\s\[v0.0.1].+?(?=---)`

I've tried using grep with the -P flag which should support PCRE style regex but doesn't seem to do much
`grep -P 'm/(?s)##\s\[v0.0.1].+?(?=---)/' CHANAGELOG.md`

The sample data I have been working on is

```
# Changelog

All notable changes to this project will be documented in this file.
Please note that all entries must end with `---` to allow for the auto release body to  use the Changelog



## [v0.0.1]

### Added
- Initial Commit/Release
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main issues I see here are:

1. The enclosing `m/` and `/` are regular expression *delimiters* – they should not be included as part of the regular expression itself.
2. `grep` is line-oriented by default, so it doesn't really do multi-line matching. At least in GNU grep, you can use null byte delimiting to kludge it, by adding the `-z` flag.

So for example,

```
$ grep -zPo '(?s)##\s\[v0.0.1].+?(?=---)' CHANGELOG.md
## [v0.0.1]

### Added
- Initial Commit/Release
```

For multi-line matching, you might consider using `pcregrep` if it is available for your platform, i.e.

```
pcregrep -Mo '(?s)##\s\[v0.0.1].+?(?=---)' CHANGELOG.md
```

Comment: Cheers will just use the pcregrep, its only for a build container so easy enough to add to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove `m//` delimiter, so :

```
grep -P '(?s)##\s\[v0.0.1].+?(?=---)' CHANAGELOG.md
```

But [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) **is not suited to be in *multi-line* mode** by default, like in your regex101 snippet.

So, [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) to the rescue :

```
perl -0 -lne 'print $& if m/(?s)##\s\[v0.0.1].+?(?=---)/' file
```

### Output

```
## [v0.0.1]

### Added
- Initial Commit/Release
```

Comment: Yeah have tried that, still returns nothing.

Comment: POST edited with perl's solution (multiline mode)